Best way to download large SharePoint read only library
I have been shared a SharePoint link to large library of zip files. Roughly 1TB. It is read only and I would like to download all the files. I can download files one at a time or in batches but have no option to link to a one drive or anything. Does anyone know if there is a good solution for this? Is it possible to write a script to do this incrementally? Trying to download the top level directory that contains all the files does not work.

You can use the SharePoint Developer Docs to learn how to access SharePoint from code. Then write the code that loops over the library and download each file.

That being said, this site isn't meant to provide tutorials or suggestions for how you do that -- it's expected that you research and make a decision on which approach you want to use, and then, if you encounter a problem or error in your code, you can ask a question about a specific programming problem or error. Keep in mind that questions need to be objective and have a definite right or wrong answer. "Best" is not qualified in a way to determine a right or wrong answer. What I think is best may not be what someone else thinks is best.

Asking for best way is off topic for being only answerable with opinion-based questions. Also it lacks focus on a problem you encountered while trying yourself. (This is basically the same as devlins comments, just mapped to closing reasons.) Also, a respectful attitude would avoid putting people into a close-vote trigger-happy mood ... hint ... hint.

You could try to use sync function in sharepoint.

Please refer to following document
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b
